# Avoid text field from getting focus when calling setValueOf for CKEditor dialog plugin

Tags: ckeditor

I have a CKEditor dialog plugin as follow

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('myDialog', function( editor ) {

    editor.on( 'dialogShow', function( dialogShowEvent )
    {
        ...
        dialog.setValueOf('tab-xxx', 'seperator', ", ");

    });

    return {
        title: 'xxx',
        minWidth: 200,
        minHeight: 100,

        contents: [
            {
                id: 'tab-xxx',
                label: 'xxx',
                elements: [
                {
                    type: 'text',
                    id: 'seperator',
                    label: 'xxx'
                }]
            }
        ],
```

When `dialog.setValueOf` is being performed on text field, it will get focus automatically. This caused the entire value being selected.

[image]

I wish to avoid my newly inserted value, being selected. I had tried to shift the focus to other UI component

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('myDialog', function( editor ) {

    editor.on( 'dialogShow', function( dialogShowEvent )
    {
        ...
        dialog.setValueOf('tab-xxx', 'seperator', ", ");
        // Shift the focus, hopefully the text in 'seperator' will not be selected.
        dialog._.buttons['ok'].focus();            
    });
```

However, that doesn't help. May I know what is the correct approach to do so?

Comment: Are you sure that `setValueOf()` moves the focus to the input field? TBH, I find it rather unlikely and I even checked right now that if the focus was on a button it will stay there. Could you create a sample perhaps?

Comment: Pretty sure. When I remove `setValueOf`, no text will be selected. If I revert back `setValueOf`, the text will be selected. I will see how I can provide a minimum workable sample.